# NullPointerException in Spinner onItemSelected

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

i get NullPointer in spinnerview onItemSelected

Error code

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method nh.nawafil.hidayatullah.release.ui.home.ui.nawafil.NawafilFragment$setupListView$1$3.onItemSelected, parameter view
    at nh.nawafil.hidayatullah.release.ui.home.ui.nawafil.NawafilFragment$setupListView$1$3.onItemSelected(Unknown Source:7)
```

my spinner code

```
spTahajjud.adapter = customAdapter
        spTahajjud.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                paramsPost["tahajjud"] = position
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {}
        }
```

i dont know the problem, but the problem occure when i switch to other fragment and go back to this spinner fragment

Comment: Something is calling that method with a `null` `View`. The stacktrace should tell you what. The solution may just be to declare it as nullable: `view: View?`.

Answer (score 0):

i just an answer for my question

i implementing onItemSelectedListener in my fragment, and after that using onItemSelected and onNothingSelected outside onCreated